# Delegate didSelectRowAt Not being called for some cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

didSelectRowAt is not being called for some custom cells. I am also using a gesture recognizer on the tableView. I tried to override shouldReceive

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
return true
//return false
}
```

for both cases, true and false, didSelectRowAt was not called for the concerned cells. User interaction is enabled on the custom cells

Comment: Did you add tableView.delegate = self in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Do your custom cells respond to didSelectRowAt if you remove the gestureRecognizer?

Comment: Try removing gesture from tableView. Also check if tableView delegate is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First **gesture and didSelect** does not work at same time.but if you want to enable tableview gesture and didSelect for custom cell you need to check for current view in below method

```
 func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view!.isKind(of: Your Custom Cell){
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the gestureRecognizer and connect your `UITableView` Delegate and DataSource from the code or using storyboard like this.

```
tableview.delegate = self
tableview.datasource = self
```